# share firestore collection paths across admin and web

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to make re-usable functions that get the Firestore Document/Collection reference across web and admin (node.js).

for example:

```js
getUserDocumentReference(company: string, user: string) {
  return firebase.collection("companies")
    .doc(company)
    .collection("users")
    .doc(user);
}
```

This will reduce errors and coordinate changes across both environments.

**Problem**: Admin imports firestore from `firebase-admin`, and web imports from `firebase`.

I've tried making some class/function where I pass in my `firestore` reference, but it becomes a pain where I have to declare the return types:

```js
const ref = (
    getUserDocumentReference("a", "1") as 
      firebase.firestore.DocumentReference
    )
    .withConverter(converter)
```

Is there a smarter/cleaner way to do this without re-inventing the wheel (i.e. somehow passing an array or re-creating paths in a complex way)?

---

my current approach:

```js
class FirestoreReferences {
   constructor(firestore: firebase.firestore.Firestore
  | admin.firestore.Firestore) {
      this.firestore = firestore;
  }

  getUserDocumentReference(company: string, user: string): FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference | firebase.firestore.DocumentReference {
     return this.firestore.collection(...).doc(...);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found out about [Typesaurus](https://typesaurus.com/index.html) which provides generic types to share across web/admin!

Answer (score 2):

I recently encountered a similar challenge where we needed to share model types between client and server Firestore. The main obstacle is the different Firestore types for Reference and Snapshots between `firebase` and `firebase-admin`, especially when these types are consumed in varying environments (browser SDK / admin SDK).

Here's the solution I implemented:

1. Separate Firestore types package:
   we created a package `@myorg/firestore-types` that serves as a placeholder for Firestore types. By default, this package exports the ***client-side** Firestore types* as default.
2. Use the `@myorg/firestore-types` package in your shared types and functions:

In our shared `@myorg/firestore-models` package, rather than pulling types directly from `firebase` or `firebase-admin`, we referenced them from our `@myorg/firestore-types` package.

```
import { Firestore, DocumentReference } from "@myorg/firestore-types";
import { User } from "@myorg/firestore-models";

// Gets a reference to a user document.
function getUser(
  firestore: Firestore,
  userId: string
): DocumentReference<User> {
  return firestore.doc(`users/${userId}`);
}
```

3. Override types when necessary:

In the `admin-sdk` environment, we took advantage of TypeScript's module augmentation to override the types in `@myorg/firestore-types` to align with the `admin-sdk` types. Here's a brief example:

```
declare module "@myorg/firestore-types" {
  export type Firestore = import("@google-cloud/firestore").Firestore;
  export type DocumentReference<T = any> =
    import("@google-cloud/firestore").DocumentReference<T>;
  export type CollectionReference<T = any> =
    import("@google-cloud/firestore").CollectionReference<T>;
  export type Query<T = any> = import("@google-cloud/firestore").Query<T>;
  export type QuerySnapshot<T = any> =
    import("@google-cloud/firestore").QuerySnapshot<T>;
  export type DocumentSnapshot<T = any> =
    import("@google-cloud/firestore").DocumentSnapshot<T>;
}
```

This effectively switches the internal types used by our shared models for the `admin-sdk` ones.

---

This approach is enough for us since we are only dealing with References and Query. If you want to share other types, they might have different APIs between the two SDKs, so it might not be as straightforward or even possible to share them.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer: DO NOT use the `.doc()` or the `.doc().ref`.  Use the `.doc.ref.path` - which is a string with the FULL PATH to the document.  Save/share it as `let refPath = whatever.doc().ref.path` and re-build it as `.doc(refPath)` is either environment.

I DO NOT actually RECOMMEND this - it exposes your internal structure - but it isn't inherently insecure (your security rules better be taking care of that).

btw, I'm building an entire wrapper npm package (@leaddreamer/firebase-wrapper) for this specific purpose.

Answer (score -2):

You should not do this. The Admin SDK is meant for server-side usage because it has full control over your entire project. If a user gets access to this, they have control over your app. Keep `firebase` and `firebase-admin` seperate.

Comment: they won't have access if using admin in the browser since it doesn't have the service account.

Comment: If they don't have access to a service account, what is the purpose of using the Admin SDK in the browser?

Comment: as described in the question, it's in order to make a single _shared_ functions which would work in both environments.

Comment: How would you share the function?

Comment: my project has a `frontend`, `backend` directory, both using the shared scripts.

Comment: I guess you could do that, however since this is a weird use case, making TypeScript work properly will be a challenge.

Comment: If you have the AdminSDK in the client, and it is able to access data, then you have the credentials in the browser where they CAN be stolen.  Full Stop.